# Can't check user_actions permission for the access_token in facebook API explorer

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, access-token

in the permission selector popup i can't find the user_actions permission checkbox. Is that quite normal ?

I want test this kind of request /me/music.listens or /me/music.playlists for a future app.
For now, the return give me an empty array.

Thank you

Comment: you can manually request it for a particular action type by copying the URL of the auth dialog and adding the permission you need into the URL (e.g. user_actions.music for music)

Answer (score 0):

Look at this URL: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/permissions/

It shows you how to request permissions for a specific action or a specific app along with some sample code. Once you get the token you can check it's permissions using the debug tool here: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DOM inspector to change the name attribute of one of the permission checkboxes that you don't need to "user_actions.music".